# Use the keyboard to emulate a mouse

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

My mouse is broken. How can I use the keyboard as a mouse on Raspbian?
I need to resize the terminal window (and other windows in general), plus doing other tasks like I would if using a mouse.

Comment: Under x11/gnome System Settings MouseKeys
https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/mouse-mousekeys.html.en

Comment: @AvinashRedy Please do not use code markup (`like this`) for things that are not code.